# Starting a postgres SQL 9.6 Server on Amazon Linux returns unrecognized service

Tags: postgresql, amazon-linux

I am attempting to start a Postgres SQL server on amazon Linux using the command

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

I installed the server using [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/831962/installing-postgres-server-9-6-on-amazon-linux/916075) method. I have added it here for simplicity

```
sudo rpm -i https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-96-9.6-2.noarch.rpm
```

and then

```
sudo yum install postgresql96-server.x86_64
```

after which i did this to install the command line tools for postgres

```
sudo yum install postgresql96.x86_64 postgresql96-libs.x86_64
```

Any suggestions on how I can start the server ? I usually start the server using 
the command

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

however its not working in this case as it says "Unrecognized service"
I then tried this

```
postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
postgres: could not access directory "/usr/local/pgsql/data": No such file or directory. Run initdb or pg_basebackup to initialize a PostgreSQL data directory.
```

Comment: I have seen environments where the version number is in the service name, have you tried `sudo service postgresql-9.6 start`?

Comment: yes it says service unrecognized

Comment: How do I run initdb in this case ? Normally I would do `sudo service postgresql initdb` ?

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue, or similar. May be I installed pgsql from source, don't remember. We could make our own service start files. How? Let's find out! >>RTFM<< starting with what we already know:

```
man service
```

which leads us to chkconfig(8), so

```
man chkconfig
```

and it gives us an option

```
chkconfig --add ${svcname}
```

to add a brand new service under a name we choose!

But before we do, we might actually want to check what's already there. With

```
service --status-all
```

we get a list of all known services and their run status. And I found "postmaster" in my list, and as you might know, the PostgreSQL master server to connect to used to be called "postmaster". Yet, when I try

```
service postmaster status
```

it also tells me it doesn't know such service. OK, forget it -- for now -- just let's move on with making our own! But I still want to peek what there is in run-level 3 (normal server run level). So I go

```
ls -1 /etc/rc.d/rc3.d |fgrep post
```

and there I find: "K36postgresql95"! So, accordingly our service name should be "postgresql95". Trying that:

```
service postgresql95 status
```

it says now "postmaster is stopped". Confusingly the name the service reports for itself both in service --status-all and when we individually inquire for it is different than the name used to actually address it in the service command. Good to know. Easy enough to search /etc/rc.d for the name of interest.

```
service postgresql95 start
```

now starts the service. And check with

```
psql -U ${pguser} ${pgdb}
```

and I find that working. So now all I need to do is enable that service at system boot to auto-start

```
chkconfig --levels 3 postgresql95 on
```

and that works, doesn't it?

PS: It doesn't matter that I happen to run version 9.5

Comment: Really loved this answer. Learned a lot and solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed PostgreSQL 9.2.24 on **Amazon Linux 2** and I had to initialize the database manually before being able to create `ROLE` and `DATABASE` as I normally would on Ubuntu.

```
// initialize database after installing with yum
$ sudo postgresql-setup initdb

// start
$ sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
```