# postgresql-setup command and postgres service not found on AWS Linux

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, service, amazon-linux

I have been configuring an EC2 instance with postgreSQL according to the steps outlined [in this tutorial](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow/wiki/Setting-up-PostgreSQL#ec2). I am using AWS Linux 2018-03 and have installed `postgres92` via the following:

```sh
$ sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib postgresql-docs
```

My understanding is that I should be able to directly initialize postgres with:

```sh
$ sudo postgresql-setup initdb
```

as noted in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453173/starting-a-postgres-sql-9-6-server-on-amazon-linux-returns-unrecognized-service) (note: it would appear I need to conduct this step as well, I'm unable to run postgres as a service just yet). However, calls to `postgresql-setup` return:

```sh
sudo: postgresql-setup: command not found
```

I've also tried a `find / postgresql-setup` just to see if this is hanging around on the system somewhere, but this turns up nothing. I am unable to start postgres via `sudo service postgres ...` commands, as the service is not yet recognized. I have confirmed that the service is not running via:

```sh
$ sudo service postgres status
```

which just tells me that the service is unrecognized and I have also checked with a `ps -ef | grep postgres`, which also turns up nothing.

My question remains, **how do I initialize postgres so that it can be recognized as a service** given that `postgresql-setup` cannot be located? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue with a slight modification to the configuration instructions found in the referenced tutorials/questions.

#### 1. Different calls for initializing database

It appears postgresql made some fairly major name changes around v9 such that `postgresql-setup --initdb` and `postgresql-setup initdb` are now equivalent to `initdb`.

First, might need to change permissions/ownership to the data directory. Typical user is `postgres`.

```sh
$ sudo chmod 775 /var/lib/pgsql92
$ sudo chown USER /var/lib/pgsql92
```

The initialize the database with:

```sh
$ initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql92
```

May have to `sudo -u USER ...` to run this depending on current role, but I finally received:

> Success. You can now start the database server using:
>
> postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql
>      or
>      pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql -l logfile start

#### 2. Different service name

Finally, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453173/starting-a-postgres-sql-9-6-server-on-amazon-linux-returns-unrecognized-service) proved to be extremely helpful in diagnosing issues surrounding postgres as an unrecognized service. Many popular tutorials out there suggest `sudo service postgres start`, but a check of run-level-3 services (not that I know what that is, but [this Gunther Schadow guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666635/gunther-schadow) sure does) with

```sh
$ ls -1 /etc/rc.d/rc3.d | fgrep post
```

shows that we should really be calling the service as **postgresql**. If we do the following:

```sh
$ sudo service postgresql initdb
$ sudo service postgresql start
```

we actual get the service to run and the rest of the process is just configuration through `psql`, which works as expected.